# `sfrac` with fraction numerator and denominator

Tags: amsmath, fractions, xfrac

I want a fraction of derivatives, so I use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\begin{document}
    Good: $\sfrac{4}{5}$
    
    Not good: $ \sfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}} $
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the result is not very beautiful:

[image]

At the first fraction 4 is in a higher level than 5. But it is the opposite at the second fraction.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: \sfrac uses \scriptstyle, while \dfrac uses \displaystyle.  The other two sizes are \textstyle and \scriptscriptstyle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sole purpose of using `\sfrac` is to typeset fractions more compactly than is possible with `\frac`. Using `\dfrac` in the arguments of `\sfrac` flies in the face of using `\sfrac` to begin with.

If you simply *must* use fractional expressions in the arguments of `\sfrac`, do give `\sfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}` a try, i.e., use `\frac` (or `\tfrac`) instead of `\dfrac`. However, just omitting the `\sfrac` wrapper and thus writing `\frac{dy}{dt} \big/ \frac{dx}{dt}`  would appear to be a better alternative.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xfrac,array}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}

\begin{tabular}{l >{$}l<{$}}
 Sort of OK     & \sfrac{4}{5} \\
 Terrible       & \sfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}} \\
 Still not good & \sfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} \\
 Better         & \frac{dy}{dt} \big/ \frac{dx}{dt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were very helpfull!